# What do i need to know about dynamic programming?

Tags: java, c++, c, algorithm, performance

Started up solving UVa problems again as a way to pass time (going to the army in 6 weeks). I love writing Java, but end up using C / C++. It's not because IO is faster, no need to box data, more memory or use of unsigned, because its algorithm efficiency that counts.

In short i am slowly constructing how to/article/code base for different categories of **efficient algorithms** and dp is next.

Quoting Mark Twain: It ain't what you don't know that gets you into trouble. It's what you know for sure that just ain't so.

I aid assistance in building priority list what are must have **efficient algorithms**.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you test the times of C vs Java?  There was one case where a bunch of really good coders ported an algorithm to a handful of languages and in that case Java was faster than C until you hit -o3.  C jumped ahead at the higher optimization levels, but I don't think it ever got more than 2x.  I'm just curious if you tested because it sounds like you might have and I could use more data points along these lines...

Comment: Could you please provide more information on the term "dynamic programming"? Do you mean dynamic dispatch (polymorphism) or dynamic program generation?

Comment: Dynamic algorithms usually run faster than any time requirements, or they're not dynamic. So efficiency is not an issue.

Comment: Here is one of my favorite dynamic programming posts: http://research.swtch.com/2008/06/electoral-programming.html

Comment: I believe that Java can be fast, especially if implementation is well written and run on Sun Servers specially designed for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wikipedia article on [Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) has a section entitled "[Algorithms that use dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming#Algorithms_that_use_dynamic_programming)" with many examples.

Here is another good list of [practice problems in dynamic programming](http://people.csail.mit.edu/bdean/6.046/dp/).

Since you referenced the UVa problem list, you should definitely take a look at [Problem 103 - Stacking Boxes](http://acm.uva.es/p/v1/103.html). The problem lends itself well to a solution using a [Longest Increasing Subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) algorithm.

Comment: If you have tried UVA 103 and would like an explanation by example, have a look at [this blog post](http://ruslanledesma.com/2016/03/25/stacking-boxes.html).

Answer (score 4):

[This MIT lecture](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=5819552931286083215&hl=en) is a good introduction to dynamic programming if you're already familiar with algorithms.